# sql query to get redundant record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get redundant records from the database. Is my query correct for this?

```
select (fields) 
from DB 
group by name, city
having count(*) > 1
```

If wrong please let me know how can I correct this.

Also if I want to delete duplicate record will it work?

```
delete from tbl_name 
where row_id in 
   (select row_id from tbl_name group by name, city having count(*) > 1)
```

so i can make the above query like this

```
DELETE FROM tb_name where row_id not in(select min(row_id) from tb_name groupBy(name, city) having count(*)>1)
```

Comment: You will have to explain a little better than that. Which database are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server db. i also want to know how else can i make query to get duplicate record from DB

Comment: what do you mean duplicate records..I mean does this table have duplicated records or just you want to take one record duplicated?

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DELETE` syntax is definitely totally wrong - that won't work ever. What it'll do is delete **all** rows that have more than one occurence - not leaving **any** data around...

What you can do in SQL Server 2005 and up is use a CTE (Common Table Expression) and the 
`ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function:

```
;WITH Duplicates AS
(
    SELECT 
      Name, City, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, City ORDER BY City) AS 'RowNum'
)
DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE RowNum > 1
```

You basically create "partitions" of your data by the `(name, city)` combo - each of those pairs will get sequential numbers from 1 on up.

Those that have more than one occurence will also have entries in that CTE with a `RowNum > 1` - just delete all of those and your duplicates are done!

Read about [Using Common Table Expressions in SQL Server 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml) and about [Ranking Functions and Performance in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/ranking_functions_performance_p1.aspx) (or consult the MSDN docs on those topics)

Comment: so i can make it like this DELETE FROM tb_name where row_id not in(select min(row_id) from tb_name groupBy(name, city) having count(*)>1)

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: you can't make it that way - you need to use the CTE approach I showed in my answer - that will delete the duplicates from your table

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax wrong:

```
select name, city, count(*) from table group by name, city having count(*) > 1
```

If you are not interested in the actual count, remove "`, count(*)`" from the query

Comment: how else can i make query to get duplicate record?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: i am seeking for some other way to creat it too

Comment: no i just looking for logic, syntax is not an issue but still i am looking for some other option to make it. Can u provide me some where i can learn all good query practice of this kind?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Microsoft itself recommends this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444 Now, why do you need an alternative? Is it too slow? Use nolock: http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/sqlforduplicates.html